# OAuth: Unable to use AWS EC2 instance for Authorized redirect URIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth, credentials, credential-manager

I am trying to use the URL of my AWS EC2 instance for my Authorized redirect URI but I am receiving an error: 'Invalid Redirect: must use a domain that is a valid top private domain '

What are my options?

This is the AWS URL I am trying to add:

http://ecx-x-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000/user/google/callback

Answer (score 0):

You do not own `amazonaws.com`. You must use a domain that you own/control. In most cases that means purchasing your own domain name. You must also have published a working website with that domain.

[OAuth Client Verification Requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requirements)

[Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?ref_topic=7440006)

[OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)